# Add progress chart on my web pages

Tags: graph, charts

i want to add this type of progress graph in my site pages.

can any one plz help me

[img link is here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=hb9rDRckulZCwM&tbnid=w8eSIUEN3TLM2M:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fpic-165259793%2Fstock-vector-modern-financial-graph-chart-template-for-business-design-infographics-reports-progress.html&ei=qOD-U8DxIoTmuQSNloKABQ&bvm=bv.74035653,d.c2E&psig=AFQjCNG5Y26yGCVL24UUOti5FtL4ejICHg&ust=1409298514480461)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript charting library to create a live, interactive version of the chart for your site. That way, you can update your progress instead of coding a new static chart each time you want to update it.

Here is [an example of a time series line chart](http://www.zingchart.com/playground/run/53ff94d9a6f3b) made using [ZingChart's library](http://www.zingchart.com). It is a bit different than the image you shared, because it has a Y axis. I'd recommend using one so your users know what is being measured across time.

I'm on the ZingChart team so please feel free to reach out if you have any questions.